# How to add Cakephp generateTreeList order by field

Tags: cakephp

How to add order by field  in Cakephp generateTreeList model function. Please tell a solution to get this result.

Comment: the output of generateTreeList method having sorted order

Comment: then how can i get sorted category tree  order in cakephp?

Comment: by providing a specific example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reorder your tree first [reorder method specification](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/class-TreeBehavior.html#_reorder) and  use generateTreeList  after that.

Also, result of generateTreeList is simple array, so. you can order result by [array sorting functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php). for example by asort